# How to use onChange method in semantic react dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

Can someone help me out how to use onChange in dropdown (Semantic UI React). I am reading the docs, but still, I don't get it. It does have onChange props.

```
onChange(event: SyntheticEvent, data: object)
```

How do I use it? Like, I have method `dropdownmethod()`.

edit - implemented the suggestion, but it didn't work. I think in your suggestion, you didn't bind the function. But, I bind the function.

```
  onChangeFollower(event,data){

    console.log("on change follower",data.text)

  }

  render() {
    console.log("this.props",this.props)
    var onChangeFollower = this.onChangeFollower.bind(this)

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>project settings are here</h2>
        <h2>Add new Member</h2>

        <Dropdown onChange={onChangeFollower}
        placeholder='Select Member'
        fluid search selection options={arr} />

        <h2>List of members</h2>
        {lr}

      </div>
```

Answer (score 18):

As stated in the docs, you just need to pass a reference of your method and then you will get 2 parameters:

1. The native event
2. The object of the option selected

[Here is a running example](https://codesandbox.io/s/oxxpp897k5)

Here is a code snippet (it uses a CDN but throws some debug warnings, so ignore them)

```js
const { Dropdown } = semanticUIReact;

const languageOptions = [
  { key: 'eng', text: 'English', value: 'eng' },
  { key: 'spn', text: 'Spanish', value: 'spn' },
  { key: 'rus', text: 'Russian', value: 'Russian' },
]

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchQuery: '',
      selected: null
    }
  }

  onChange = (e, data) => {
    console.log(data.value);
    this.setState({ selected: data.value });
  }

  onSearchChange = (e, data) => {
    console.log(data.searchQuery);
    this.setState({ searchQuery: data.searchQuery });
  }

  render() {
    const { searchQuery, selected } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown
          button
          className='icon'
          fluid
          labeled
          icon='world'
          options={languageOptions}
          search
          text={searchQuery}
          searchQuery={searchQuery}
          value={selected}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          onSearchChange={this.onSearchChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui-react@0.77.1/dist/umd/semantic-ui-react.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment.

> I checked example. Even there when i type something, it doesnt show me
>   anything in console

You are not talking about `onChange` of the `select` you are talking about when the search input has changed.
You can use `onSearchChange` with same parameters. (I've updated the example)

Comment: well, it didnt work. I have updated the thread. I binded the function . But, nothing happens when i input text in dropdown.

Comment: I checked example. Even there when i type something, it doesnt show me anything in console

Comment: @AnkurSharma check my update. i thought you want to log on each optioned selected, not search input changed.

Answer (score 9):

I have implemented as below

React hooks function is as below , if you prefer you can pass `handleOnChange` as a prop as well

```
const RenderDropdown = ({optionsArray}) => {

   const handleOnChange = (e, data) => {
      console.log(data.value);
   }

   return (
     <Dropdown
        placeholder='Please select'
        fluid
        selection
        options={optionsArray}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      />
   );
}
```

options array as below

```
const optionsArray = [
  {
    key: 'male',
    text: 'Male',
    value: 'male',
    image: { avatar: true, src: 'https://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/elliot.jpg' },
  },
  {
    key: 'female',
    text: 'Female',
    value: 'female',
    image: { avatar: true, src: 'https://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/stevie.jpg' },
  }
]
```

Comment: My question is, how can you have access in the image property in the handleOnChange function? If someone wants access to more properties and not only value, how is this possible?

Comment: edit on my question above, if the question arise for someone else, just have an object value with several properties and then access each object property.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the working code of your's:

```
onChangeFollower(event, data){
    console.log("on change follower",data.text)
  }

render() {
    console.log("this.props",this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>project settings are here</h2>
        <h2>Add new Member</h2>

        <Dropdown onChange={this.onChangeFollower}
        placeholder='Select Member'
        fluid search selection options={arr} />

        <h2>List of members</h2>
        {lr}

      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use onChange event to detect the changes in the dropdown list

```
onSearchChange={(e, v) => {
        changeMethod(e, v)
}}
```

use onSearchChange event to detect the search input

```
  onSearchChange={(e, v) => {
           searchMethod(e, v)
    }}
```

and you have to define  searchMethod and changeMethod as consts in the top of your page.